# API End point deployed in AWS EKS is not Accessible Using NodePort

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy sample spring microservice using AWS EKS. After creating cluster I tried to deploy to EKS cluster having one single worker node created with t2.small. While describing service , it shows that its deployed and running.While accessing end point through node's ip address and port ( node-ip-address:31821/cicd/load ) giving `This site can’t provide a secure connection` on browser.

**I am using t2.small Amazon Linux 2 single node (Only 1 worker node) in node group.**

My Docker file looks like the following,

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/cicdpipeline-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war cicdpipeline.war
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "cicdpipeline.war"]
```

I am using following command in my deploy stage of jenkinsfile to make kubernetes deployment,

```
kubectl apply -f deployment/deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f deployment/service.yaml
```

**My deployment.yaml file,**

[image]

**My Service.yaml file like the following,**

[image]

`kubectl describe service pipelineservice` command gives the following result,

[image]

`kubectl describe pod` command giving the following results,

[image]

Accessing Output using Node Ip address , port and end URL like `node-ip-address:31821/cicd/load` typing in browser.

NB:
1 Describe pod showing status with running state.

2. Security group for ec2 ( Node) is successfully added inbound rule to allow node ports

[image]

[image]

**Update**

Warning while applying `kubectl describe pod`  command - `Warning FailedToRetrieveImagePullSecret Unable to retrieve some image pull secret (dhubauth) ; Attempting to pull the image may not suceed`

Here I am just using 1 single worker node for learning purpose. And instance type t2.small. So is this pblm because of my instance type ? Or because of my YAML file issue?

I just started to explore EKS for my learning purpose using NodePort method witout using ELB and Ingress. Can anyone suggest where I went wrong here in implementation? Or Am I taking output in wrong way? suggest any documentation which can use to resolve this type of problem please?

Comment: You should probably be using a Service of type LoadBalancer or an Ingress instead of NodePort. If you use NodePort, your nodes have to be on a public subnet. Doesn't look like your service is configured for https either.

Comment: Can you replace the CLI pictures by their actual text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.`This site can’t provide a secure connection`. This is a browser error and you are accessing the jenkins in `https` protocol. But, the jenkins is exposed in `http` protocol.

Since, You are accessing the application via Node IP which use http protocol. Please access the jenkins like below.(Make sure url prefixed with `http`)

```
http://node-ip-address:31821/cicd/load
```

2. `FailedToRetrieveImagePullSecret Unable to retrieve some image pull secret (dhubauth) ; Attempting to pull the image may not suceed`

If you are pulling image from private repository. You have to configure the ImagePullSecret. Please double check the ImagePullSecret is configured in kubernetes secret.

```
kubectl get secret dhubauth
```

If the secret is not available please follow this document to create the secret.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

3. You are trying to expose the jenkins application via NodePort. Please make sure your worker node(EC2 instance) is running in public subnet.